# Hibernate sequence not updated after liquibase import

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, liquibase

I have an empty Spring Boot application in which I want to load my data from a previous version. This data does already contain primary keys. Therefore I use Liquibase loadData method:

```
<column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="${autoIncrement}">
    <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
</column>
<loadData tableName="point_of_interest" separator=";" file="classpath:config/liquibase/data/public.poi.csv">
</loadData>

// the java annotations
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
```

This works as expected but the Hibernate sequence is not updated. Which results in duplicate primary keys if I want to save a new object.

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers, Daniel

Comment: I think with `GenerationType.AUTO` JPA will decide which strategy to use for the primary key generation and that depends on the database. So what database are you using?

Comment: Guesswork: `GenerationType.AUTO` leads to a table that has the sequence for the primary keys but these are still initiated by hibernate. When you use liquibase there is no hibernate involved and then your primary keys do not get updated. (I am not talking about a real sequence like in Oracle but a pure table that is used to store the primary keys. I think mySQL does something like this).

Comment: I'm using postgresql 9.4+

Comment: You could edit your question and show the "sequence" (from you database) that is used for the primary keys. I still think that `GenerationType.AUTO` did not create a real sequence in your postgresql db. It might be a plain table and hibernate/jpa is using that to generate your primary keys. If you use liquibase there is no hibernate thus your primary key table is not updated. You could try to set `GenerationType.IDENTITY` instead and see if that creates a real sequence. Then the primary key generation is done on the database and should also work with liquibase...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution (copied form the jHipster team) to this problem is to increase the start value of the hibernate sequence. This allows you to insert all the data with IDs < **startValue** and so no collisions will occur:

```
<changeSet id="00000000000000" author="jhipster" dbms="postgresql,oracle">
    <createSequence sequenceName="hibernate_sequence" startValue="20000" incrementBy="1"/>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Daniel's answer, assuming you are using Spring, Hibernate with liquibase, adding a sequence in you changelog

`<changeSet id="00000000000000" author="jhipster" dbms="postgresql,oracle">
    <createSequence sequenceName="hibernate_sequence" startValue="20000" incrementBy="1"/>
</changeSet>`

and modifiying your primary-key column in your entity to use `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` would solve this issue.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
private Long id;
```